# SQL Redshift: How to use a value in a join based on another columns value

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift

i have a table with columns such as this:

```
name   product    existing_customer
john   crisps     yes

paul   cheese     no

george broccoli   no

ringo  spam       yes
```

but in order to populate this table as such I'm referencing this layout:

```
name       value.      tag
john       crisps.     product
john       yes.        existing_customer
george     broccoli.   product
george     no.         existing_customer
etc        etc
```

I need the output like the first table, I have tried it with case statements but it is showing multiple lines with the same name and showing each value separately.

Is there a way to do this in redshift SQL?

Comment: And where does "ringo" come from?

Comment: same as john and george

Comment: Can you guarantee that 1) your input has always exactly 2 rows for each name and 2) they are always in correct order?

Comment: @VesaKarjalainen . . . SQL tables represent *unordered* sets so your second question makes no sense.

Comment: @GordonLinoff I know that. But the question makes no sense unless it was meant that the input is a CSV or some other ordered stream

Comment: @VesaKarjalainen they are both tables in a database that I am joining on

Comment: Then you probably have to code some logic to separate that a "yes" means it's a `existing_customer` value and a "broccoli" is a `product` value.

Comment: question updated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use aggregation:

```
select name,
       max(case when tag = 'product' then value end) as product,
       max(case when tag = 'existing_customer' then value end) as existing_customer
from t
group by name;
```

Answer (score 0):

With the new input, something like:

```
select * from 
( select name, value as product 
  from in_values 
  where tag='product') as p
full outer join 
( select name, value as existing  
  from in_values 
  where tag='existing_customer') as e 
using (name);
```